# Can I use std::upper_bound without an underlying container?

Tags: c++

I have a range of integers `[start, end]` and a non-decreasing monotonic function `f(i)`.
So conceptually, I have a non-decreasing sequence `[f(start), f(start + 1), .. , f(end)]`.
Can I use `std::upper_bound` on that sequence to find the first element `i` in the range that holds `f(i) > some_value` ?

Conceptually, I'd like something like this:

```
std::upper_bound(start, end + 1, some_value, [&](int lhs, int rhs) { 
    return f(lhs) < f(rhs);
});
```

But this doesn't compile because `start` and `end + 1` do not meet the requirements of [forward iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator).

Comment: So `start` and `end` are just plain integer values? Then no you can't use `std::upper_bound`. Almost all algorithmic functions rely in iterators. It should be easy to [generate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) values for a container though.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yep it would be easy, but I'd rather avoid the performance hit

Comment: @Shmoopy If you don't want to fill a container, you can create range iterators (like `range()` in python), or find existing implementation.

Comment: There is no good way to do this within the constraints of the current standard. There are things you can do that are technically UB, but will likely work in practice, and will likely eventually become well-defined.

Comment: @T.C. could you please provide an example?

Comment: With the upcoming Ranges TS you can do exactly that. Or you could use the range-v3 library in the mean time

Comment: @iehrlich There's no way to satisfy the requirement that `reference` be a real reference and that for two deferenceable iterators `a == b`, `*a` and `*b` be bound to the same object without having some kind of actual external sequence of integers.

Comment: @T.C. yes, already thought about it :-/

Comment: STL works on pointers, so you need to be specific what your "range" is.

Comment: Isn't that std::max ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is yes, since `std::upper_bound` works on iterators, not on containers. But iterators themselves are instances of corresponding class (for example, `std::vector<int>::iterator` or whatnot).

If you construct some specific class that will meet the requirements of `ForwardIterator` not being actually bound to some sort of container, while still meaning something (for example, if you want to generate your sequence procedurally), it should work just fine.

Note that simple integer will not do the trick. On the other hand, a class, whose objects hold the value of your function for a particular argument value (with some additional batteries), will.

Comment: [`boost::integer_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) is such an class

Comment: I don't think a `T*` is a class, but it makes an excellent ContiguousIterator.

Comment: @caleth no, that does not qualify.  Boost forward traversal read only does not match the standard requrements for a forward iterator.

Answer (score 7):

There are basically two answers:
Would it work by the standard or would it work with all practical implementations of the STL?

By the standard, as [T.C. pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006750/can-i-use-stdupper-bound-without-an-underlying-container#comment76988245_45006750) already, there are some strict requirements on iterators, especially that `*it` has to return a (possibly const) reference to `value_type` (which we would satisfy by returning the reference to a member of the iterator), but we also need that for `it1 == it2`, `*it1` and `*it2` are references bound to the same object, which is only possible if we have a distinct object for every number in the range.

If you want to do use this idea in practice, I don't believe any implementation of `std::upper_bound` or similar methods actually relies on this reference equality, so you could just use a class that encapsulates an integer as an iterator, only overloading the [necessary methods](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). As far as I can see, [`boost::irange`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) fulfills these requirements

As you can see, this is not strictly standard-compliant, but I see no reason why any implementation of binary search should rely on such strong requirements for the iterator, if the underlying 'storage' is const anyway.

Comment: Just a small comment: std::upper_bound needs just ForwardIterator [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator], RandomAccessIterator is not necessary

Comment: @ChristianG while this is true, for performance reasons: "However, for non-RandomAccessIterators, the number of iterator increments is linear." thus eating up the large speedup compared to linear search

Comment: You are right, this is more "theoretical" possible with FwdIt than being feasible : )

Answer (score 3):

No, not practically, but yes in practice, but no if you want to be practical.

## No

`upper_bound` requires [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator).  ForwardIterator requires that `*` returns an actual reference, *and* that if two iterators are equal then they refer to the same object.

## Not practically

For a container-less iterator, this requires an insanely complex iterator that caches the values it returns in a shared global map of some kind.  To make it half practical, note that the iterator requirements say very little about the lifetime of said reference; so you'd want to reference count and destroy said values as the iterators in question cease to exist.

Such a solution requires synchronization, global state, and is significantly more expensive and complex than something like [`boost::integer_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html).  No sane person would write this except as an exercise demonstrating why the standard needs to be fixed.

## But yes in practice

No sane implementation of `upper_bound` *actually requires* that the iterators in question are full-scale forward iterators, barring one that does full concept-checks to validate against the standard (and not against what the actual algorithm needs).  Input iterators with stability on the values returned almost certainly does it.  There is no such concept in the C++ standard, and forward iterator is the weakest iterator category in the standard that satifies it.

This problem, of effectively demanding iterators be backed by containers, is a flaw in the standard in my opinion.  Container-free iterators are powerful and useful, except they rarely technically work in standard containers.

Adding new iterator categories has proved problematic, because there is little way to do it without breaking existing code.  They looked into it for contiguous iterators, and wrote it off as impractical (I don't know all the details of what they tried).

Adding new iterator *concepts* that are not backed by tags is more possible, but probably will have to wait until concepts are part of the C++ language and not just the standard; then experimenting with adding new concepts becomes something you can specify in C++ instead of in standardese, which makes it far easier.

## But no if you want to be practical

This does, however, result in an ill-formed program, no diagnostic required.  So consider if it is worth it; it may actually be easier to reimplement `upper_bound` than maintain a program whose every excution is undefined behavior, and every compile at the mercy of a compiler upgrade.

Comment: Great answer! What I'm a bit confused about: Is it undefined behavior if you rely on the fact that all implementations of said function only require a weaker iterator concept? So far I only know cases where UB resulted from (mis)use of the language, not its standard library.

Comment: @TobiasRibizel The program is ill formed if you violate the preconditions of the standard library functions. The behavior of an ill formed program is undefined by the standard.  Practically, most standard library functions are implemented in-language, the standard is not written as if they are; instead, it defines *what they require* and *what they do if you meet those requirements*, not *how they are implemented*. Some standard library functions cannot be implemented in C++ without the standard library, so that makes sense, and it also gives room for implementors to write *better* versions.

Comment: @TobiasRibizel As some practical problems that could result, your next version could *check* that you pass the concepts and fail to build.  Or maybe they'll actually store things in references and expect them to persist past iterator modification, causing "classic UB" of dangling pointers/references.  In effect, once you violate the standard, every new compiler version becomes a headache as you should validate your "well, it works in practice" every single time.

Comment: Contiguous iterator stops being discriminated in C++20 right?